# Java RegEx does not match when using less than (<) sign

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use this RegEx in Java:  in the following code:

```
public class Intervals {
public static void main( String[] args ) {
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader( new File( "ex11.intervals.txt"));

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( fr );

        while( br.read() != -1 ){
            String currentLine = new String( br.readLine() );

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "<hr( +size *= *[0-9]+)? *>" );

            Matcher m = p.matcher( currentLine );

            while( m.find() ){
                System.out.println( currentLine );
            }
        }

    } catch( FileNotFoundException fne ){
        fne.printStackTrace();
    } catch( IOException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

But it does not work, but if I execute it using **egrep** UNIX utility it works correctly.

**ex11.intervals.txt** content:

```
<hr>
<hr >
<hr size=15>
<hr size =    21 >
```

Somebody knows what is happening with this?

I have tried

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "<hr>" )
```

But neither works.

Any suggestions, help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Change your code to read the file as follows:

```
String currentLine = null;

while( (currentLine = br.readLine()) != null ){

}
```

When you do `read()` you always read the first character thereby skipping your less than sign in the HTML tag.

Comment: Also, move your Pattern.compile(...) statement out of the loop and reuse it.

Comment: Thanks dinukadev. I was so concentrated in RegEx than other relevant details.

Comment: No probs. Glad to help :). Cheers